# I have number of days and i want to convert this given number into years and months days in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate Customer life time value for which I need the variable " Number of years the customer is with the company". but I have it in days . So i want to extract number years from the given number . Like Datedif() function in excel

I tried dividing the number by 365 . But it is not accurate .

```
data$Customer_Duration
  [1]  368 1649  594  218  952  723  313
data$Cust_duration_years=round((data$Customer_Duration/365),2)
data$Cust_duration_years
> data$Cust_duration_years
  [1] 1.01 4.52 1.63 0.60 2.61 1.98
```

when i do `datedif()` function in excel . I get the some minute differences .
Like 2 observation is 1649/365 = 4.52 in R and in excel it is 4.6

Comment: independent of your R problem: `datedif()` in excel is known to produce wrong results, since it is only a backcompatibility implementation for old LOTUS sheets // To your R Problem: What exactly do you want? The full year, a decimal value for the year or year + number of month?

Comment: oops ... Okay thanks for your reply .I want it, if 368 is my number of days , I need a answer as number of year.number of months as my output .

Comment: have a look at the `pastecs` package

Comment: Should we just assume a average number of days in a month? Like 30? Because otherwise this won't be possible

Comment: Is dividing by 365.2422 not accurate enough?

Comment: Fine ... Will try dividing with 365.2422. Hope it works accurate .

Comment: No need to approximate. You can define days in months as a vector and thereby determine the years, moths and days - see answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to convert days into years months and days for the common year (could easily extend it to cover leap years):

```
days_toymd = function(days){

  year_days = 365
  month_days = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

  ## number of years
  yr = round(days / year_days, 0)

  yr_lo = days %% year_days

  month = 0
  ## number of months
  for(i in month_days){

    if(yr_lo >= i){
      month = month + 1

      yr_lo =  yr_lo - i
    }

    else if(yr_lo < i){
      yr_lo = yr_lo
    }
  }

  print("days converted to years, months and days")
  return(paste(yr, month, yr_lo))

}
```